# SQL: Checking whether dates are present in both tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables

**RejectionDate**:

```
'2016-07-01'
'2016-08-01'
'2016-09-01'
```

**PayDate**:

```
PayDateStart     PayDateEnd
'2016-08-01'    '2016-09-01'
```

I need to check whether all dates from the first table `RejectionDate` fall into periods stored in the other table `PayDate`.

Comment: So, what would be the result that you want to get from your sample data?

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Specify the expected result too. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: So what problem have you faced? Task you've described can be solved in one join.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can get a flag per row -- which I am guessing is the real intention of the question. Regardless of the database you are using:

```
select r.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from paydates pd
                          where r.rejectiondate between p.PayDateStart and p.PayDateEnd
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as InRangeFlag
from rejections r;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join them?

```
select rd.*
from RejectionDate rd
inner join PayDate pd
on rd.RejectionDate between pd.PayDateStart and pd.PayDateEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS all_dates, COUNT(t2.PayDateEnd) AS all_between_dates
FROM Rejections AS t1
LEFT JOIN PayDate  AS t2 ON t1.RejectionDate BETWEEN t2.PayDateStart AND t2.PayDateEnd
```

The first `COUNT` returns the number of all records of the first table, whereas the second `COUNT` returns the number of all records of the first table that have a date that is between start/end date of the second table.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/BYL87408)